# how to get fans profile for a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala

I was looking a way to get all the fans for a specified page, of course the user logged should be also the administrator for this page.
I'm playing with koala and I can get the id for a page in this way

`@graph.get_object("myfanpage")['id']`

but how to retrieve the fans profile?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to retrieve a list of page fans via the Graph API.

When browsing facebook.com as a page admin, you can click the 'people like this' link under the number of fans and view them in a popup, but this cannot be done programmatically.